# Terraform: Can it be used to spin up reserved infrastructure for short periods of time?

Tags: terraform

I've just learned about Terraform at the highest level and I'm wondering if it's something I should look into for the following purpose:

I'm developing a toy project and exploring the idea of a quick "back-up-and-share-your-own-data" type of feature. The user would mostly need to access their data when they open or save a document (more of a periodic sync than a pub-sub model). It would be great to allow users to capitalize on DigitalOcean's hourly rate.

Would it be possible to just use a tiny persistent volume on DigitalOcean, then programmatically...

- Spin up a minimal droplet in response to a (client-side) application event
- Hook up to a DigitalOcean floating IP address
- Run for just the 1-2 minutes of operation time required
- Then destroy the droplet?

This feels like cheating... is this a use-case for Terraform or would I basically be reinventing the wheel when I should just be using the provider API?

Comment: sounds like you need a digital ocean equivalent of aws lambdas!

Comment: How long would you spend spinning up and tearing down your infrastructure to actually do 1-2 minutes of work? Is your end-user tolerant of that delay? There isn't anything in terraform preventing you from doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: That's a good point about the delay. I'd say that they would be OK with that, it can be done in the background. @RaGe, reading about Lambdas now, seems like a competitive option!